# WPF Telerik Issue

Tags: wpf, telerik, wpf-controls

I am leveraging the WPF Telerik libraries for a simple Tab control. Weird enough the exact same code/solution works on my personal computer but gives the following error on my office machine:

Code

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="900">
<Grid>
    <telerik:RadTabControl>
        <telerik:RadTabItem Header="Dashboard Summary" Width="200" Background="Gray">
        </telerik:RadTabItem>
        <telerik:RadTabItem Header="Details" Width="200" Background="Gray"  />
        <telerik:RadTabItem Header="Policy Tester" Width="200" Background="Gray"  />
    </telerik:RadTabControl>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

The exact same 3 libraries are being referenced but the same code on my office machine renders the tabs but doesnt give me intellisense and keeps throwing the following error:

[image]

Has anybody seen issues like this?

Thanks

Comment: How are you referencing Telerik libraries? Are you using a direct reference to a DLL which holds your controls or do you have some automation mechanism which is making these references available inside VS?

Comment: Direct Reference through Add Reference Dialog in Visual Studio

Comment: make sure to double check the Telerik namespace, for me its xmlns:Telerik="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls", and it should be something similar for you as well.

Comment: Vibhore - Checked with the the namespace you have given. Have seen it on telerik forums too but that didnt help too unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

Add the following references
    Telerik.Windows.Controls
    Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation
    Telerik.Windows.Controls.Data

And make sure they are added to your GAC
    gacutil /I "Location of Dlls"